# When opening SAP NetWeaver Business Client I get "nwbc.exe has stopped working"

Tags: runtime-error, netweaver

Looking for some help with the error I get when trying to start SAP.

When trying to start SAP this error keeps popping up:

> nwbc.exe has stopped working

I’ve done a full reinstall of SAP and the error still occurs. There were errors after both uninstall and reinstall.

[image: reinstall error log]

[image: uninstall error log]

[image: error]

Regards,
David